@PreUpdate and @PostUpdate have the same entity values
I am using JPA Entity Listeners to track changes in my entity.
I created the below EntityAuditListener class, and I Used @preUpdate to capture the old values before being updated. But the values appear inside this method are the new values (after updating), they are the same values in the @PostUpdate method. How can I capture the old values of the entity before being updated? I want to log save them to a database table. I want to do this for my whole application (large number of entities), is there a better approach?
Moreover, I got an error when I tried to save the audit using the service. The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
┌─────┐
|  jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory
↑     ↓
|  entityManagerFactory
↑     ↓
|  service.EntityAuditListener
↑     ↓
|  auditTrailService
↑     ↓
|  auditTrailRepository
└─────┘
I tried to inject the repository directly in the EntityAuditListener, and I tried EntityManager, JDBCTemplate but all give the cyclic dependency error. Any Advice would be helpful.
@Component
public class EntityAuditListener {
    @Autowired
    private AuditTrailService auditTrailService;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager   entityManager;


    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate(Object entity) {
        String oldValues = getOldValues(entity);
        System.out.println("Pre Update happens");
        System.out.println("Previous value before update: "+oldValues);
        // Here I will save teh old values using the service
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void onPostUpdate(Object entity) {
        System.out.println("Post Update happens");
        String newValues = getNewValues(entity);
        System.out.println("new Entity: "+newValues);
    }
    
    private String getOldValues(Object entity) {
        return serializeToJson(entity); 
    }

    private String getNewValues(Object entity) {
        return serializeToJson(entity);  
    }

    private String serializeToJson(Object entity) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to serialize entity", e);
        }
    }
}

The entity:
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "tags")
@EntityListeners(EntityAuditListener.class)
public class TagEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TAG_ID")
    private Long tagId;

    @Column(name = "TAG_CREATED_BY")
    private String tagCreatedBy;

    @Column(name = "TAG_CREATED_ON")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp tagCreatedOn;

    @Column(name = "TAG_UPDATED_BY")
    private String tagUpdatedBy;

    @Column(name = "TAG_UPDATED_ON")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp tagUpdatedOn;

    private String tagName;

    private Integer tagActive;

}


